# Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1 Build Issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-2015

Following a change from Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise to Visual Studio 2015 Community (with Update 1), none of my projects build.

The errors I see in the error list are as follows -

1. The "Csc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
2. The "Features" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task. Verify
   the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public
   instance property.

Having Googled extensively, I can't seem to find anything helpful.

Comment: There are a number of features not supported by the Community edition, and it sounds like you may have the use of some of those features embedded in the project or solution file.  Create new project and solution files, adding all the same source files and then build from those.

Comment: "Features" in the context of this error has nothing to do with the Community/Enterprise split.

Comment: I have the same error in VS2015 Enterprise. It occurs deterministically after creating a new empty AspNet 4.5 project.

Comment: I resolved it in Visual Studio 2015 & Visual Studio 15.0 Preview by removing Roslyn Compiler extension and other Roslyn product  from extension manager.

Actually it was installed when I was doing experiment with Roslyn source code (hosted a GitHub) for new compilers and new Visual studio instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow you have mismatched your C#/VB compilers. Your project files are trying to pass a property we added to a newer version of the compilers, but you're still running an older version of the compilers. It's unclear based on your description if that's all projects that are broken, or just some. Things I would check:

1. If just some projects don't build, make sure you don't have our compiler NuGet packages installed but you didn't run restore.
2. If you had some experimental version of the Roslyn compilers installed that you forgot about, make sure that's still installed.
3. If all projects don't build (including you just building a brand new one) verify there's nothing strange installed under the Extension Manager. If there is nothing, then do a repair install of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Roslyn Insiders for VS 2015" extension fix it for me.